# In CSS, how can I make a navigation menu that overlaps a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm wondering the best approach for creating an overlapping navigation. I guess the easiest way is just to position it absolutely relative to the containing div? Any thoughts on an easy way to position this would be great!

I'm currently considering using a bootstrap button group for the "nav".

[image]

Comment: It appears you are trying to center this, yes?  You can actually accomplish this with position: relative (for both the nav and the div), and give the div a negative `margin-top` to "suck" it up underneath the nav.  I personally would wrap the buttons in an additional div, so you can use text-align center and have the browser naturally keep them centered in that space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with minimal pure css, and without position absolute.

In order to keep your nav centered, I would recommend some markup along the lines of below (a wrapper around your nav to let you center it up).

Note that I understand you intend to use bootstrap, and you will absolutely be able to do that with what you are trying to accomplish. The below is just pseudo-code to get you the key elements / working example of how this could be accomplished.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naegkd2o/)

Basic markup:

```
<div class="nav">
  <nav class="buttons">
    <a href="#">Button 1</a>
    <a href="#">Button 2</a>
    <a href="#">Button 3</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="content">
    Borderered content area.
</div>
```

Demonstrative CSS:

```
div.nav {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

nav {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: white;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.content {
  margin-top: -15px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid red;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

**Note**
With this markup, you will end up with about 4px of space between the `<a>` elements due to the whitespace.  See this article: [Fighting the Space Between Elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

My typical solution is to move the elements onto the same line.  Not quite as readable, but gets the job done, and doesn't require any other "funky" solutions:

```
<nav class="buttons">
    <a href="#">Button 1</a><a href="#">Button 2</a><a href="#">Button 3</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: This looks great! will go test it out now. Thanks!

Comment: any idea why there's margin between each nav element? I added margin: 0; but nothing happened

Comment: @NickONeill - absolutely! It's due to the whitespace because each <a> element is on it's own line.  If you move them so that they are on the same line, it will resolve the issue.  I'll improve the answer to explain.

Comment: Got it ... I switched it to UL > LI to fix that issue

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
}

.nav div {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="nav">
        <div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="header">

</div>
</body>
```

or you can go with just one div in the nav bar putting `left: 25%`